# Deleting All Non-Recently Updated Keys/Inserts MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a DELETE statement in Java where after updating and inserting all new items into the DB, it deletes any old ones that were not affected by the update.

**Reasoning**: I'm hosting a game where items are saved upon logging out. Items are either updated or inserted depending on whether or not their reference exists. However, it *is* possible that a player could have dropped an item inside the game, thus no longer having ownership of it. I need to delete the reference to this item now that the player no longer has it.

**tl;dr**: Trying to write a DELETE FROM WHERE NOT IN for all non-updated objects belonging to the character

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `inventoryitems` (
  `inventoryitemid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `characterid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `inventorytype` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `owner` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `petid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `flag` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `expiration` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `giftFrom` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`inventoryitemid`),
  KEY `CHARID` (`characterid`),
  KEY `inventorytype` (`inventorytype`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `accountid` (`accountid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=79597880 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide some table definitions and, preferably, some sample table data. Helping your is quite hard, otherwise.

Comment: I'll get right on it. @J.N. updated with table definition

Comment: delete all items in the database for the character .. then insert all items the character have .. you dont need to update it one by one or delete if dropped by the character

Comment: Try reasoning about it - what data would indicate that the inventory item was affected? How would it show it?

Comment: @J.N. Well Hmm. Inside the game a player could trade or drop the item. When logging out their items would save, but I would have to get rid of their reference to the inventoryitem since it could be anywhere now. 

Therefore it seems I would have to do as Demonyowh said and delete the items then reinsert. But that also causes problems since I have 2 indexes and it slows down insertion speed, thus resorting to an UPSERT hybrid.

Comment: @Demonyowh That's what I had previously, but indexes slow down the save a lot. I tried changing to an UPSERT update to optimize saving but that's an issue now :/

Comment: I think this is completely off track. The right approach is to delete the item as an when it's 'dropped'

Comment: @e4c5 That can't be considered because items are dropped all the time and making database calls on delete would be bad since hundreds of items are dropped by players. Additionally, dropped items can be picked up by another player.

Comment: That tells me that you have a badly designed database as well. You need to have an items table and you need to have another table linking players and items. A dropped item only needs to be deleted from the player-item table.

Comment: Also FYI a single row delete/insert/update/select scales beautifully if you have created the proper set of indexes on your table.

Comment: Just curious about this... By what you explained I'm foreseen a really messy data track here by numerous scenarios. For one, you said that you do the operations when the user logs out, so what happens when his connections goes down? About your problem you are constantly inserting/updating/deleting rows all the time so that tends to make things slower. I agree with @e4c5 here. And with this you could easily implement the "run operation when it happens"

Comment: @e4c5 My current indexes are accountid, characterid, inventorytype, and type, which is a lot of indices, probably slowing down everything.

By having another table linking the two, do you mean just having one table with just characterid to inventoryitemid reference and that's it? If possible, could I PM you instead of turning this into a long conversation.

Comment: I think at this stage, it's best if you could take a break from coding and read up on database normalization.

Comment: @e4c5 You're probably right. Do you have any MySQL books you can recommend?

Comment: No don't read a mysql book. This is database agnostic. There are plenty of good tutorials online for normalization.